# How to test PHPUnit an authenticated user on Laravel with API middelware?

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, testing, phpunit

I'm triying to test a route and endpoint that requires an authtenticated user, but i'm getting some troubles. ¿How can I login an user in my test function?

- My database model is not an Eloquent-Model.
- I'm using phpUnit for testing

**ENDPOINT**:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/myroute', 'MyController@MyFunction');
```

**CONTROLLER** (it works OK on frontend):

```
public function MyFunction()
{
  $loggedUser= auth()->user()->getAuthIdentifier();
  $results= $this->myUsecase->execute(new myCommand(new UserId($loggedUser)));
  return $this->response($this->serializer, $results);
}
```

**TEST**:

```
function testMyControllerCanSendResults()
{
    $response = $this->get('/api/myroute');
    $response->assertOk();
}
```

This test fails because the app nedds an authtenticated user to get his Identificator used in an *Usecase*.

I've tryed to make a custom Fake Factory for 'Usuario' model (but i've problems because my 'Usuario' model isn't a Eloquent Model.

What can I try? **Thanks a lot!!!**

Comment: Are you using Laravel Passport?

Comment: @Saly3301 no. I'm using a custom guard:         'custom' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'model' => Usuario::class,
            'table' => 'users',
        ],

Comment: Did you register the custom guard to be used by the api in `config/auth.php`?

Comment: Yes @Saly3301     'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
//////////////////
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'custom',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'custom',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

    ],

Comment: if your driver is `database` then you can't use `'model' => Usuario::class,`

Comment: But de App works perfectly whit this configuration.... :S ... what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

@Saly3301

this is my "login" function:

```
public function doLogin(Request $request){

    $username = $request->input('username');
    $password = $request->input('password');
    if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['user' => $username, 'password' => $password])) {

        $user = Auth::user();

        $respuesta['api_token'] = Auth::User()->api_token;
        $respuesta['id'] = Auth::User()->id;
        $respuesta['rol'] = Auth::User()->rol;
        $respuesta['status'] = 200;
        return $this->response($this->serializer, $respuesta);

    } else {
        $respuesta['status'] = 400;
        return $this->response($this->serializer, $respuesta);
    }


}
```

Once user has logged, 'api' middleware works ok (i'm usen api_token in request from frontend -that it's a React-admin frontend)

Answer (score 0):

```
/** @test */
public function unauthenticated_user_cannot_access_protected_routes()
{
    $this->expectException('Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException');

    $this->getJson('/api/user');
}
```